# Why am I seeing Runtime error 3421 - access vba?

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2007

I have been using a vba code to make my work life easier but for some reason it stopped working as supposed to. What it does it gets a number from my DB and goes to website to find relevant certificate assigned to this number (company), then it reads the grade and expiry date which are to be recorded in same DB. The issue is now when it goes to

**rs.fields("Expiry").Value = Split(sResult, "|")(1)**

it throws a Runtime error 3421 which i believe is due to column being formatted as for date data type but it worked correctly for several months..? It work when changed data type to text however that will mess it up as later I use it in queries and reports and need it as a date.

Any ideas why it changed and how to fix it please?
Thanks
MD

```
Sub Get_BRCDirectory_Data()
Dim sCode, rs As DAO.Recordset, dic As Object, sResult As String, i As Long

Set dic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
dic.CompareMode = 1

Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Approved")
If Not (rs.BOF And rs.EOF) Then
    rs.MoveFirst

    Do
        sCode = rs.fields("SupplierCode").Value
        
        If sCode <> "" Then
            If Not dic.Exists(sCode) Then
                sResult = GetGradeExpiryDate(CStr(sCode))
    
                rs.Edit
                rs.fields("Grade").Value = Trim(Split(sResult, "|")(0))
                rs.fields("Expiry").Value = Split(sResult, "|")(1)
                rs.UPDATE
                dic(sCode) = Array(rs.fields("Grade").Value, rs.fields("Expiry").Value)
            Else
                rs.Edit
                rs.fields("Grade").Value = dic(sCode)(0)
                rs.fields("Expiry").Value = dic(sCode)(1)
                rs.UPDATE
            End If
        End If

        rs.MoveNext
    Loop Until rs.EOF
End If

MsgBox "Done", 64
```

Comment: What is a typical value for `sResult`?

Comment: A text is not a date, even if it looks like - if it worked, VBA/Access converted it automatically by guessing the format. This is error prone, convert it explicitly.